# Evaluating pyscipopt Expr after optimization

Tags: python, scip

I have a question regarding PySCIPOpt: Is it possible to evaluate expressions (pyscipopt.scip.Expr) after optimization? Similar to calling getVal() for arguments of type pyscipopt.scip.Variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not (yet) possible to query the activity of a general constraint. This is only possible for linear and quadratic constraints, see http://scip-interfaces.github.io/PySCIPOpt/docs/html/classpyscipopt_1_1scip_1_1Model.html#a1e79bf20f168f7c55aa3fdf00491c898

You could turn your expression into an equation and check the value of the new slack variable:

```
c(x) >= b
```

turns into

```
c(x) - s == 0
s >= b
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am not just talking about constraints. E.g. if I have a variable assigned
x = scipModel.addVar(vtype='C', name='x', lb=0, ub=1)
and specify y = 10*x, then y is assigned the type pyscipopt.scip.Expr. Is is possible to evaluate y later?

Comment: I see. This would require an extension to the Expr class. Would be quite useful I suppose.  https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/280